# Handling api calls in Redux with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, redux, axios

Good evening everybody!

I'm a total beginner in React and Redux so please bear with me if this sounds totally stupid. I'm trying to learn how I can perform some API calls in Redux and it's not going all to well. When I console log the request from the action creator the promise value is always "undefined" so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

My goal is to grab the information from the data inside the payload object and display them inside the component. I've been trying to get this to work for the past days and I'm totally lost.

I'm using Axios for and redux-promise to handle the call.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the output from the console.

[image]

[image]

**Action Creator**

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_FLIGHT = 'FETCH_FLIGHT';

export function getAllFlights() {

const request = axios.get('http://localhost:3000/flug');
console.log(request);
  return {
    type: FETCH_FLIGHT,
    payload: request
    };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import { FETCH_FLIGHT } from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FLIGHT:
    console.log(action)
      return [ action.payload.data, ...state ]
    }
   return state;
  }
```

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { getAllFlights } from '../actions/index';
import Destinations from './Destinations';

class App extends Component {

componentWillMount(){
  this.props.selectFlight();
}

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
  this.state = {
 };
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
    );
 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
   dest: state.icelandair
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({ selectFlight: getAllFlights }, dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: What wasn't working for you? Your code looks OK. redux-promise wants the payload to be a promise and it looks like that's what you're supplying.

Answer (score 43):

`axios` is the promise so you need to use `then` to get your result. You should request your api in a separate file and call your action when the result comes back.

```
 //WebAPIUtil.js
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/flug')
  .then(function(result){ 
    YourAction.getAllFlights(result)
  });
```

In your action file will be like this :

```
export function getAllFlights(request) {
  console.log(request);
  return {
    type: FETCH_FLIGHT,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, please mark this as an answer. While I personally like redux-axios-middleware, this is indeed the best answer and should be marked as one for futures sake!

Comment: I don't understand how this works. Where are you calling the `axios.get` from?

Comment: @AlanSchapira it is imported to your file using `import axios from 'axios'`

Comment: How are you calling the webAPIUtil in the action?

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with thunk.  https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

You can dispatch an action in your `then` and it will update state when it gets a response from the axios call.

```js
export function someFunction() {
  return(dispatch) => {
      axios.get(URL)
        .then((response) => {dispatch(YourAction(response));})
        .catch((response) => {return Promise.reject(response);});
    };
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I also think the best way to do this is by redux-axios-middleware. The setup can be a bit tricky as your store should be configured in a similar way:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import axiosMiddleware from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import axios from 'axios';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

const configureStore = () => {   
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(axiosMiddleware(axios))
  );
}

const store = configureStore();
```

And your action creators now look like this:

```
import './axios' // that's your axios.js file, not the library

export const FETCH_FLIGHT = 'FETCH_FLIGHT';

export const getAllFlights = () => {
  return {
    type: FETCH_FLIGHT,
    payload: {
      request: {
        method: 'post', // or get
        url:'http://localhost:3000/flug'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post demo where how I can trigger the method api from connect method

Answer (score 5):

The best way to solve this is by adding redux middlewares http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html for handling all api requests.

https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware is a plug and play middleware you can make use of.

Answer (score 5):

I took care of this task like so:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const receiveTreeData = data => ({
  type: 'RECEIVE_TREE_DATA', data,
})

export const treeRequestFailed = (err) => ({
  type: 'TREE_DATA_REQUEST_FAILED', err,
})

export const fetchTreeData = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get(config.endpoint + 'tree')
      .then(res => dispatch(receiveTreeData(res.data)))
      .catch(err => dispatch(treeRequestFailed(err)))
  }
}
```